# Allocating 2 dimension array of a class Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is working just fine.

```
test [][] matrix = new test[5][];

    for(int i =0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
        matrix[i] = new test[5];
        for(int j = 0 ; j< 5 ; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = new test();
        }
```

This is not working

```
for(test[] t: matrix)
        {
        t = new test[5];
        for(test t2: t)
            t2 = new test();
        }
```

This is working

```
int[][] matrix2 = new int[5][5];
```

without to initialize at all

The question is why ?

Comment: I think both works? What is the issue?

Comment: you can check it , the second one is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are assiging to a local variable and not to an element of `matrix`.

```
for(test[] t: matrix) {
    t = new test[5]; // You are assiging to a local variable
    // t is a local variable!
}
```

To make it more obvious:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    test[] t = matrix[i]; // t is obviously a local variable.

    // This will assign a new array to the local variable t:
    t = new test[5];

    // matrix[i] is still null, to prove it:
    System.out.println(matrix[i]); // Prints "null"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  t = new test[5];
        for(test t2: t)
            t2 = new test();
```

assigns a reference to an element within an array and then *reassigns* that reference to point to a new `test()`. What you want to do is assign the array element reference e.g.

```
 test[2] = new test();
```